# VBA Copy Module from one Workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

Hello thanks for reading my question. I'm trying create an automated script that exports a module from one workbook to another new workbook

```
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Coexis_BitAND").Export ("c:\Coexis_BitAND.bas")
        wbNew.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("c:\Coexis_BitAND.bas")
```

However, when I step through the code as soon as the step hits  "ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Coexis_BitAND").Export ("c:\Coexis_BitAND.bas")" It jumps to one of my OnError Goto's.

I've read it's possible to do this but have yet to find something that works, I'm sure it has to be something simple like my lack of experience with VBA

Comment: What is your Macro Security **Trust** setting(s) **??**

Comment: It says Disable all macros with notification

Comment: and Turst access is VBA Project object model is unchecked

Comment: Please review the following before proceeding:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Thanks that doesn't sound like a good way to go, would there be a better way to do an export of a module, like ThisWorkbook.Activate then open an export file dialog then wbNew.Activate and open an import dialog?

Comment: Oh, I meant to say that my method above was not a good way to go from what you asked me to read...thanks good info

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both work books are open at the same time, give this a try

```
Dim comp as VBComponent
Set comp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Coexis_BitAND")
Workbooks("otherWorkbookName").VBProject.VBComponents.add comp
```

Comment: Yup, might even need to add VBIDE in front of VBComponent. So it would look like        VBIDE.VBComponent

Comment: Option Explicit seems to be the variable. Without it VBComponent is fine. With it one would need to add the VBIDE part.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the times you cant step through the code when programing the VBIDE.  Even if your Code is 100% it will Err on Step.

Place a Stop just outside of where you bugOut & just let it run to the Stop. If it hits an Error with your Code still. You could verify your code against [Chips](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) function:

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found worked, from the original answer, thanks for all the help.

```
        If DUTs = 0 Then
        '----- WARNING VBA Macro Settings must Trust access to VBA Project Object Models.
        '----- Antivirus may detect this action and delete this file!
        filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Coexis_BitAND").Export (filePath + "\Coexis_BitAND.bas")
        wbNew.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import (filePath + "\Coexis_BitAND.bas")

    End If
```